Does gsutil cp use up local storage?
I am now copying a large file from a GCS bucket to Google Drive using a Colab notebook with:
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
project_id = 'my_project_id'
!gcloud config set project {project_id}    
!gsutil -m cp -r (path_to_the_file_in_bucket) /content/google_drive/My\ Drive/

However, as I copied, I found the storage inside the Colab notebook VM is simultaneously being consumed:

May I know if it is a normal behavior?
How can I prevent the VM from using up its storage under /content/ ?

Colab is that the files you upload to it won’t be available forever. Colab is a temporary environment with an idle timeout of 90 minutes and an absolute timeout of 12 hours  whatever you write in the /content/drive/My Drive folder can be seen in Colab and itself will expire after a few hours, taking local storage with it. check this link
